# How to use MediaElement in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, mediaelement.js

I am trying to render a YouTube Video in the `<video>` tag.

I run `npm install mediaelement`

**MediaComponent.html**:

```html
<video width="640" height="360" id="mediaPlayer" #mediaPlayer preload="none">
    <source type="video/youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI" />
</video>
```

**MediaComponent.ts**

```js
import * as MediaElementPlayer from 'mediaelement'; // How to import it?

@Component({
  selector: 'app-media',
  templateUrl: './media.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./media.component.css']
})

export class MediaComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  //...
  @ViewChild('mediaPlayer') mediaPlayerElement: ElementRef;
  public mediaPlayer;


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    //..
    this.loadMediaPlayer();
  }

  loadMediaPlayer() {
    this.mediaPlayer = new  
            MediaElementPlayer(this.mediaPlayerElement.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

The console is clear. But nothing happens on the page. I think somethings wrong with import statement or calling the Constructor

**How can I use [MediaElementJs](http://www.mediaelementjs.com/) with Angular?**

Note: It's so interesting there is ReactJs documentation on [the official page](https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement/blob/master/docs/usage.md#react) but for Angular, nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You should add this line in the `main.ts`.

```
import 'mediaelement';
```

And then you should use it with the following declaration.

```
declare var MediaElementPlayer;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer now I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of null" is it related with jquery?

Comment: I don't think so. I tried it in a new project and it worked fine without any dependencies.
I think the error is because of the other part in your code.